# What is the meaning of the name Ziesenis or Zieseniss?

Tags: translation, meaning, person-names

One of my ancestral surnames is Ziesenis and I'd like to know what it means. They were Prussian immigrants to the US back in the 1800s.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Ingmar: Please see [this Meta discussion](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/890/2594).

Comment: Do you know any more about the part of Prussia they were from? Maybe they were from East Prussia, which would mean their name is likely of Slavic origin. (The way the name looks suggests it.) Prussia at its peak extended from Eupen in the West to Lyck (today: Ełk) in the far East and from Rödding in the North (part of Denmark) to Sigmaringen in the South (although the area around Sigmaringen was a pretty remote exclave of Prussia).

Comment: @Jan You're right that the name doesn't look very German. I had conjectured that it might be Baltic, but then I checked http://www.gen-evolu.de and Wikipedia. It turned out that the name occurs almost exclusively around Hanover, and that a familiy of painters and sculptors named Ziesenis lived in that region already in the middle of the 17th century. That doesn't exclude an East Prussian/Baltic/Slavic origin, but it makes it somewhat less likely.

Comment: I'm explicitly voting to keep this question **open** due to the results of the meta discussion.

Comment: Ziesenis ist der Name von Malern und Bildhauern. Könnte Dir jemand den Wunsch zur bildenden Kunst mitgegeben haben?

Answer (score 4):

We definitely can't give you concise directions on the genealogy of German surnames within the scope of this site dedicated to language.

Nevertheless some hints on the language aspect of this name may help:

1. **Ziese *f.* / Ziesen *pl.***
   This used to be a name for [taxes](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ06212#XGZ06212) in Preussia, similar to the sales taxes today. It is unclear as to why the suffix **-(n)is** was added, but from common understanding of this [suffix in other nouns](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/nis.html?MenuId=WordFormation110419&lang=en) it may have had a meaning roughly like *"who was attached to taxes"*.
2. **Ziese *f.***
   This is a name of a [small stream](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziese) in the north-east of Germany. As names often come from locations we can speculate that somebody added a latinising suffix **-nis** to indicate "of origin near the Ziese".

Answer (score 3):

Zieseniss is a family sur-name meaning 'found on the Ziese (a small stream once found in Germany)'

Most of my family tree can be traced back to two German brothers that lived near the Ziese'

Comment: Would be interesting to know, where this stream is/was. Are there any references to back up the given explanation?

Comment: @Arsak Zur Frage wo: Guck mal den Link in Punkt 2 von Takkats Antwort